# How to make my Android activity use its xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a very simple app that accepts user text as input and returns it. The app seems to work except I want a button below the returned user input. Right now it simply returns the text with no button despite the fact that I have added the button to the activity's xml file. I even see the button on the graphic view of the xml file so I know that the problem must be finding a way to connect the xml file with the DisplayMessageActivity.java file. Below is the a snippet of my DisplayMessageActivity.java file where I think I am doing something wrong. Perhaps I should not call the setcontentview function?

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intention1=getIntent();
    final String message = intention1.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);

   // Set the text view as the activity layout
      textView.setText(message);
      setContentView(textView);



    }
```

Comment: do you mean `setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml);`? could you show your xml layout?

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@layout/activity_display_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/user_inp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: you need to replace textView in the line setContentView(textView); with your xml layout. R.layout.layout_file_name. Then you should see the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling setContentView(TextView)? You have to inflate the complete layout file that represents your Activity layout ie;

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout).  //Inflate the layout of your activity
```

Then you have to inflate your Button from that parent layout so you would have something like

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  //Inflate the button that is inside 
                                                      //that layout
```

Your onCreate should looking something more like this

```
private Button button;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);   //Call this  first

   button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
   button.setOnClickListener(this);


   //Inflate whatever other buttons/views you have inside your activity here
```

Make sure you also definte you  in the same layout file for your activity. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Button` here at all. What you want to do is call `setContentView()` then you can `inflate` a `View` from that if you want to add a `TextView` to. `setContentView()` merely `inflates` whatever `View`/`Layout` you tell it to. Here, you are telling it to only `inflate` the `TextView` you have created.

There are a couple ways to do this but the most common would be to do something like
add the `TextView` to your xml (we will call it `main.xml`. You can set the properties there and change them in Java if you need/want to. Then set your `layout`

```
  TextView tv1;
  Button btn1;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intention1=getIntent();
    final String message = intention1.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);          
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);  // where activity_display_message is the name of your xml file
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1); // assuming text1 is the id in xml of your TextView
    btn1 = (Button) findVieById(R.id.btn1); // assuming btn1 is the id in xml of your button
   }
 }
```

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@layout/activity_display_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/user_inp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: No, your `id` for your `TextView` should be like `android:id="@+id/text1` text1 can be anything but that's how you define your `TextView` in your Java code

Comment: Ok, let me know if it helps or if you're confused